# Doubly Linked List Node Problems

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

```
int listSize = 0;
CalendarLinkedList firstList = new CalendarLinkedList();
CalendarLinkedList currentList = firstList;
for(int a = 0; a < listSize; listSize ++)
        {
            currentList = firstList.next;
        }
        CalendarLinkedList newList = new CalendarLinkedList(todayDate, listSize + 1);
        newList.setPrev(currentList);

        currentList.setNext(newList);

        currentList = newList;
```

This is one part of my linked list, will the nodes be alligned properly?
Because it seems like newList is not going next to currentList properly.

listSize is like a counter.

I thought if I write my codes like this, a new list will come next to firstList, then the current will become the new List. Am I wrong?

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Trying to see if the nodes alligh themselves or not

Comment: What do you mean by "align"?  Are you trying to add a node to the end of a list, or insert a node in the middle of a list, or something else?  What is the goal of your program?

Comment: I meant allign as add new list at the end, yah, seems confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the variable `firstList` points to the head of the list you want to add to, you probably want something like this:

```
int listSize = 0;
CalendarLinkedList currentList = firstList;
while (currentList.next != null)
{
    currentList = currentList.next;
    listSize++;
}
CalendarLinkedList newList = new CalendarLinkedList(todayDate, listSize + 1);
newList.setPrev(currentList);
currentList.setNext(newList);
```